# React Native TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClient' of null

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to create a React native application that uses Bluetooth to communicate with an Esp32 microcontroller. I've been using https://dotintent.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/ to set up Bluetooth on my React native application.

the problem I am facing is each time I run the application with the following code snippet

```
import { BleManager } from "react-native-ble-plx;
const manager = new BleManager();
```

i get the following error

```
Uncaught Error

Cannot read property 'createClient' of null
```

i have tried using console.log to locate issues, and even following some youtube tutorials to sort it out

extra information
i am using Javascript

```
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-ble-plx": "^3.1.2",
```

and i am using ExpoGo on an Android phone.

Comment: Have you rebuild your app? Also, check it [here](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/issues/1133).